# TinyMCE onsubmit does not fill the textareas.

Tags: javascript, forms, tinymce, tinymce-4, onsubmit

Can you tell me please how can I get the WYSIWYG content on form submit to corresponding textareas?

I have javascript validation on form submit, BUT when the validation code is triggered editor textareas are empty. So I still get an error "Field is required...". I don't understand how TinyMCE handles this, but it makes no sense. My event listener for js validation is at the very end of the scritps but textareas are still empty.

Is there some trigger to force TinyMCE to fill the textareas with content onsubmit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, TinyMCE will automatically update the underlying `<textarea>` when the form is submitted via standard HTML form submission.  This is built-in behavior in TinyMCE as the overhead of keeping the `<textarea>` constantly in sync is not needed for most applications.

If you are not relying on a standard HTML form submission event you have a couple of options...

**When you start the AJAX form submission process:**

TinyMCE has a `triggerSave()` method that forces the editor to sync with the `<textarea>` immediately.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave

You can call the `triggerSave()` first thing when your user wants to submit the form and then perform your validation.

**TinyMCE Events:**

As your response to your own question shows you can certainly rely on various editor events to sync the editor to the `<textarea>` via the `triggerSave()` method.  There is no technical issue  with this just know that you will likely trigger a large number of these events if you rely on something like the change event.  If you have large/complex HTML content or many editors on one page constantly syncing with the underlying `<textarea>` may impact the browser's performance.

**Which is better?**

*If you DON'T need real time validation of the content...* just calling `triggerSave()` at the start of the AJAX submission process is probably easier (no TinyMCE configuration code tied to an event needed) and creates less overhead for the browser.

*If you DO need real time validation of the content...* using an event like the change event to sync the `<textarea>` is the better solution.  It might look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#myTextarea",
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('change', function () {
          tinymce.triggerSave();
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: The only thing I want to say about this behavior is - It is absolutely user(coder) unfriendly interface. I tried to use "submit" event instead of "change" but it makes the same problem. My question is: Why TinyMCE does not support CONVENTION OVER CONFIGURATION principle, and for users which don't need validate the content (Who is it?) or make an ajax requests, there could be some callback to trigger triggerSave(). So important thing like validation on client side should have native support for submit. And of course this HAS TO BE the clear part of the documentation(it is not).

Comment: @Čamo can you create a demo of how you tried to use the submit event?  I use standard form submit events to trigger interactions with TinyMCE without issue.  There is no "submit" event in TinyMCE so you can't use the `editor.on()` API calls for a submit event (no such event exists).   As for convention over configuration we do just that - you have to do nothing to get TinyMCE to mimic a standard `<textarea>` in a standard web form.  You only need to code if you want to do something non-standard like use AJAX to grab form data and submit it outside of the normal / standard web form UI.

Comment: @Čamo also curious why you downvoted the answer.  Per the SO guidelines..."Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."  While I understand you want the editor to behave differently was my answer sloppy, incorrect or without effort?

Comment: So I am very sorry. I made a test with pure HTML and TinyMCE and it works right. The problem is in the framework which I use to handle js validation. Solution was specific for TinyMCE in this FW. So again - I am sorry.